# Как использовать ArrayList из одной активности в другой?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

В одной активности есть:

```
List<Start_Item> mData = new ArrayList<>();
```

Можно ли этот массив вызвать из другой активности?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: В одной активности есть: List<Start_Item> mData = new ArrayList<>();,можно ли этот массив вызвать из другой активности?

Comment: Вносите правки в тело вопроса (кнопка "править")

Comment: как static объявите да используйте, хотя это не лучшее решение.

Comment: если не трудно,можно подробнее

Answer (score 0):

Activity друг с другом взаимодействуют при помощи Intent-ов. Если вы запускаете одну Activity из другой Activity, то можно передать ей какие-нибудь данные. Например, тот же ArrayList.
В Activity, из которой будет передаваться список и из которой будет запускаться другая Activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyOtherActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("data", mData);
startActivity(intent);
```

Затем, чтобы получить эти данные в запущенной Activity:

```
ArrayList<Start_Item> data = getIntent().getSerializableExtra("data");
```